# How to get CMake to pass either std=c++14/c++1y or c++17/c++1z based on GCC version?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, gcc4

GCC 4.x doesn't accept the `--std=c++14` switch for C++14 code - it takes `--std=c++1y` instead. Later versions take `--std=c++1z` but (probably) not `--std=c++17` which has not been set yet (writing this in 2016). Perhaps there are similar issues with C++11.

Does CMake have some facility (perhaps as a module) to pass the correct switch according to the GCC version?

Comment: *"Perhaps there are similar issues with C++11."* That would be c++11 vs c++0x, the former being introduced in gcc4.7/8 or so.

Comment: Btw, the old switches (0x, 1y, 1z) work just fine even on compilers that support the modern ones, so there is no *real* need to get this "right".

Comment: There **is** a need to get this "right" since passing the raw compiler flags is a CMake anti-pattern and against the whole concept of a meta-build system/build system generator.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When wanting to specify a particular C++ version, the recommended way to do this with CMake 3.1 and later is to use the `CXX_STANDARD`, `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and `CXX_EXTENSIONS` target properties, or their variable equivalents to specify target defaults. Full details can be found [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/), but the short version goes something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
# ... Define targets, etc. as usual
```

CMake should then select the appropriate compiler flag for the requested C++ standard based on what the compiler supports, or error out if it doesn't support the requested standard.

It should also be noted that CMake may upgrade the target to use a later language standard than the one specified by its `CXX_STANDARD` target property. The use of [compile feature requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards) (as mentioned in @FlorianWolters answer) can raise the language standard requirement. In fact, CMake will always pick the stronger language requirement specified by either the `CXX_STANDARD` target property or the compile feature requirements set on the target. Note also that earlier versions of the CMake documentation did not accurately reflect the way `CXX_EXTENSIONS` interacts with compile features. With CMake 3.21 or earlier, `CXX_EXTENSIONS` would only take effect if `CXX_STANDARD` was also specified, for most common compilers (since they are specified together with the one compiler flag). From CMake 3.22 onward, `CXX_EXTENSIONS` is honoured whether `CXX_STANDARD` is set or not.

Comment: should I use all 3 properties together or only one of them is good enough?

Comment: I recommend setting all three. CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD on its own doesn't guarantee that you get that C++ standard. Without CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED being set to true, CMake is allowed to fall back to an older C++ version if the one requested by CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is not available. Setting CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS to false ensures your project doesn't use non-standard C++, but just as importantly, it may affect which standard library your binaries link to. Policy CMP0128 is also relevant.

Answer (score 41):

Modern CMake code should use the [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html?highlight=target_compile_features) command to request a specific C++ standard. This can be specified as build requirement only (`PRIVATE`), usage requirement only (`INTERFACE`) or build and usage requirement (`PUBLIC`).

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.4)

project(cpp-snippets)
add_executable(cpp-snippets "main.cpp")
target_compile_features(cpp-snippets PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

Refer to the section *Requiring Language Standards* in the official CMake documentation for [cmake-compile-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards) to learn more.

Comment: What are "build requirements" as opposed to "usage requirements"?

Comment: It should also be highlighted that support for the `cxx_std_YY` meta feature was also only added in CMake 3.8, whereas the `CXX_STANDARD` family of target properties have been around much longer and `cxx_std_YY` meta features alone don't control whether or not compiler extensions can be used.

Comment: @einpoklum As used in the answer, _build requirements_ refer to things needed to build the target itself, whereas _usage requirements_ are things that anything linking against the target will inherit as a requirement.

Comment: @einpoklum I should have used the terms *Build Specification* and *Usage Requirements* as used in the [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements). Craig Scott already explained it correctly. Another great explaination can be found in the talk [Effective CMake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk) by Daniel Pfeifer. I highly recommend watching the linked video.

Answer (score 11):

Check if the compiler supports the flags? Perhaps something like

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

# Check for standard to use
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++17 HAVE_FLAG_STD_CXX17)
if(HAVE_FLAG_STD_CXX17)
    # Have -std=c++17, use it
else()
    check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++1z HAVE_FLAG_STD_CXX1Z)
    if(HAVE_FLAG_STD_CXX1Z)
        # Have -std=c++1z, use it
    else()
        # And so on and on...
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: @einpoklum No speculation, I have been using this exact code for a couple of years without problem. With both GCC and Clang (which last time I tried did not support the `-std=c++17` option).

Comment: Why maintaining your own code, when CMake offers everything your want?

Comment: @usr1234567 Backward compatibility with older versions of CMake which doesn't have the flags and settings for newer C++ standards.