# error Compile openbw/bwapi on mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, cmake

I compiled the [ExampleAIMoudle](https://github.com/OpenBW/bwapi/tree/develop-openbw/bwapi/ExampleAIModule) of openbw/bwapi on OS X,  I build it with:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt
make
```

And I got the error:

```
bwapi/bwapi/ExampleAIModule/../include/BWAPI/Position.h:378:9: warning:
      in-class initialization of non-static data
      member is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    T x = T{}, y = T{};
        ^
bwapi/bwapi/ExampleAIModule/../include/BWAPI/Position.h:378:18: warning:
      in-class initialization of non-static data
      member is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    T x = T{}, y = T{};
                 ^
bwapi/bwapi/ExampleAIModule/../include/BWAPI/Position.h:378:12: error:
      expected '(' for function-style cast or type
      construction
    T x = T{}, y = T{};
          ~^
bwapi/bwapi/ExampleAIModule/../include/BWAPI/Position.h:378:21: error:
      expected '(' for function-style cast or type
      construction
    T x = T{}, y = T{};
                   ~^
bwapi/bwapi/ExampleAIModule/../include/BWAPI/Position.h:94:19: error:
      no member named 'tie' in namespace 'std'; did
      you mean 'time'?
      return std::tie(this->x, this->y) == st...
             ~~~~~^~~
                  time
```

You can found code [here](https://github.com/OpenBW/bwapi/blob/develop-openbw/bwapi/include/BWAPI/Position.h#L378)

Comment: Have you tried to specify that you want to compile with C++11 support enabled? e.g., as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42834844/1025391 ... or use a compiler which has this setting enabled by default.

Comment: @moooeeeep thanks, it works.